# No elimina en base de datos

Tags: java

Este es mi codigo, no sale ningun error pero al eliminar no me elimina en la base de datos phpmyadmin.

```
int fila = tabladatos.getSelectedRow();

    String sql = "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE Id_cliente = ?";

    if (fila >= 0) {

        try {

            PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);

            ps.setString(1, Id_cliente.getText());  

            ps.executeUpdate();

            mostrartabla();

            limpiar();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos eliminados");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lo unico que se me ocurre es que le estas pasando un `string` cuando probablemente sea un `int`. Prueba con `ps.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(Id_cliente.getText()));`

Comment: No, me sale una excepción, el código como esta no tengo ningún error, me dice dato eliminado, el tema es que al actualizar phpmyadmin no se elimina nada.

Comment: Un par de preguntas: si te sale una excepción, podrías ponerla? De que tipo es tu columna `ID_cliente` en tu base de datos? Por otro lado, si el registro que vas a eliminar no se encuentra, no te va a dar ningun error, que es lo que creo que te ocurre

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " "

Comment: Esa exception me sale

Comment: en la base de datos es de tipo int, el registro a eliminar lo tomo de la tabla con un getselectedrow.

Comment: Hmm..segun esa excepción, creo que en `Id_Cliente.getText()` estas recibiendo una cadena vacia. O sea,que no estas obteniendo ningun Id y por eso no te elimina ningun registro.

Comment: Como hago para que me vea el registro, perdón pero soy nuevo y estoy aprendiendo

Comment: Resuelto, el problema era que debia seleccionar lo que quieria borrar y colocar el numero de id antes de eliminar

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas solucionado :)

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esto:

```
ps.setString(1, Id_cliente.getText());
```

por

```
ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(Id_cliente.getText()));
```

Comment: Por favor agrega una pequeña descripción sobre lo que hace el código que planteas como solución, y/o explica el motivo por el cual no funciona el otro.